# How to tell if Grafana session cookie is valid?

Tags: grafana

I am trying to set up a code which given `grafana_session` cookie will tell me whether it is valid for my Grafana instance

I tried using `/api/auth/keys` and passing `grafana_session` as a Bearer token but it doesn't work and I feel like it is intended to be used in a different way.

Is there a method to validate `grafana_session` using current API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it!

You can send request to `api/user` with a special header:

```
header_key=cookie
header_value=grafana_session=<YOUR_GRAFANA_SESSION>
```

Comment: How to get `grafana_session` cookie from web app first?

Answer (score 0):

There is not official API for that. But you can call some Grafana API (for example `/api/user`) with that session cookie (please note: send it as a standard cookie, not as Bearer token). If you have response code 200, then cookie is valid, otherwise it is (very likely) invalid cookie.

`curl` example:

```
curl 'https://<grafana-domain>/api/user' \
  -H 'Cookie: grafana_session=<grafana-session-cookie>'
```